# Running OpenGeoSuite on Openshift

Tags: open-source-gis, boundless-suite, cloud-gis, openshift

Has anyone been able to run OpenGeoSuite on openshift using the free 3 gears?  There is plenty of documentation on getting geoserver running on openshift there is even a [GIT repo](https://github.com/thesteve0/geoserver-on-openshift).   However I have not been able to find any documentation for running OpenGeoSuite on Openshift. The free account they offer is right at the minimum specs. Is there any documentation for this and/or an example of a site hosted using this method?  I have done the standard searching and found nothing (Google) on the subject positive or negative. It may have never been attempted, if it has I'm looking for documentation on how it was accomplished, or the reasons why it did not work.

Comment: As it stands I think your question needs improvement because it invites answers like "I have", "I'm haven't", "I have but ...", etc.  I think you should re-word it to ask something more like "Is there documentation available for getting geoserver running on openshift?", and providing a few more details about where you have looked.

Comment: It is rather broad question you asked even with not posting of what you tried- opengeosuite is just combination of several features and all these feature can be implemented at openshift with free gear e.g. see geoexplorer implementation at  http://geox-crel.rhcloud.com/composer/

Comment: It is not broad at all there are only two possible answers to the question which are: Yes, I have done it and this is how OR No, it's not possible and this is why.  That example is one "extension" included in the OpenGeoSuite, not the entire package, therefore it is not a suitable example. The question, is can the entire package be installed using only the 3 gears? It is not, Can some of them be installed but not others, using the 3 gears.

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't used OpenShift for anything practical, reading from their site I can see that it is a cloud based version of the RedHat Linux distribution.

I therefore conclude that the normal installation guide of Open Geo Suite for Red Hat Linux should be followed. Link here - http://suite.opengeo.org/ee/docs/4.5/intro/installation/redhat/install.html#intro-installation-redhat-install

However please keep in mind that only the following versions are supported:
The following distributions are supported:

- Fedora 18 and 19
- CentOS 6
- RHEL 6